# Export SQL Server table with headers to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, csv

I am exporting a SQL Server table to a CSV using php (see code below). What I am needing help with is including the headers of the columns in the export. I can do this when I export from MySQL, but cannot figure it out with SQL Server. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
<?php

// SQL Server connection string details.
    $myServer = "server";
    $myUser = "user";
    $myPass = "password";
    $myDB = "dbname";

// connection to the SQL Server
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
            or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
        $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
            or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
        $query = "SELECT col01, col02, col03, col04, col05, col06, col07 ";
        $query .= "FROM table ";
        $result = mssql_query($query, $dbhandle);

//Generate CSV file - Set as MSSQL_ASSOC as you don't need the numeric values.
    while ($l = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($l AS $key => $value){
        //If the character " exists, then escape it, otherwise the csv file will be invalid.
            $pos = strpos($value, '"');
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
            }
            $out .= '"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $out .= "\n";
    }

//free result set memory
    mssql_free_result($result);

//close the connection
    mssql_close($dbhandle);

// Output to browser with the CSV mime type
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv");
    echo $out;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-field.php , like this:
http://www.razorsql.com/articles/sqlserver_column_names_values.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding col01, col02, col03, col04, col05, col06, col07  to the first line of your $out variable before iterating through you request results will solve your problem

out .="col01, col02, col03, col04, col05, col06, col07\n"

Comment: I think this would work it I were making it static. I am actually trying to write it so that I can more-or-less use the same code on different tables.